# Dimensionless power spectrum

Tags: cosmology

According to some physics notes I'm studying, this is the dimensionless power spectrum:

$$\Delta^2(k)=\dfrac{k^3 P(k)}{2\pi^2}$$

which is defined that way so that, after integrating out the azimuthal angle, we get:

$$\Delta^2(k)\ d\ln k=P(k)\dfrac{d^3k}{(2\pi)^3}$$

Can anyone explain to me how we deduce the second equation from the first? I think there is some sort of typo but I'm not sure. I tried writing $d\ln k=dk/k$ and $d^3k=k^2\sin\theta\ dk\ d\theta\ d\phi$ but I'm not getting anywhere. How do we "integrate out the azimuthal angle" here?

Comment: The author was probably accustomed to replacing $d^3 k$ with $4\pi k^2 dk$ inside the integral without thinking too much about the associated change in the meaning of the integral sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find this to be an extremely confusing (and misleading) way of writing things down, but here's the best I can do to make sense of it. Multiply both sides by $dk/k$ and pull out a $4\pi$ on the right-hand side, yielding
\begin{align}
\frac{dk}{k}\Delta^2(k) &=\frac{dk}{k}\frac{k^3 P(k)}{2\pi^2}
\Longrightarrow
\Delta^2(k)\,d\ln k = k^2dk\,4\pi\,\frac{P(k)}{(2\pi)^3}\,.
\end{align}
Then, write $4\pi=\int d\Omega$ so that
\begin{align}
\Delta^2(k)\,d\ln k = \int d\Omega\, k^2dk\,\frac{P(k)}{(2\pi)^3}\,.
\end{align}
We can't strip off the integral sign, but they seem to, leading to
\begin{align}
\Delta^2(k)\,d\ln k=d^3k\,\frac{P(k)}{(2\pi)^3}\,,
\end{align}
since $d\Omega\, k^2\,dk =d^3k$.

So I *think* what they really mean is that if you integrate the left-hand side over $\ln k$ and the right-hand side over all space, that you get the same expression. But in my opinion, this is really misleading (also wrong, mathematically) to use that equal sign, because those expressions *aren't equal*.

Comment: I think that in your last equation you meant to put just the $d^3 k$ in the right hand side, without the $d\Omega k^2$, right? Seriously, thank you so much for your answer. I just started a PhD in physics coming from a pure mathematics background, and things like this still drive me to absolute desperation. Just why can't some physicists write things properly or at least explain what they mean...

Comment: @WildFeather I come partly from a pure math background (BS physics, MS math, then PhD physics), and I can say that this is particularly egregious, provided my interpretation is correct.  Most of the time, the hand-waving mathematical arguments are actually kind of nice, because after all, we're doing *physics* here, but yes, physicists will sometimes play *too* fast-and-loose with the mathematics, to the detriment of all.

Comment: @WildFeather Also yes, I noticed this mistake earlier and fixed it. It should be correct now.